# How to run a jmeter test from a gitlab project

Tags: jmeter, gitlab, gitlab-ci

can someone explain to me how to run a Jmeter test from a Gitlab project if this is possible.(without installing other software such as jenkins,maven,etc).

For example, I belong to a gitlab project that builds the code into an application. I simply want to add to the project's yam'l file a jmeter test to run from it's scheduled CI pipeline process.
For example:
Load tests:
variables:
GIT_STRATEGY: none
stage: load tests
script:
- cd "\apache-jmeter-5.4\apache-jmeter-5.4\bin"
- .\jmeter -n -t JmeterTest.jmx -l testresults.jtl
only:
variables:
- $TESTTYPE == "loadtest"
artifacts:
paths:
- testresults.jtl

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about [Gitlab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/) - it naturally supports execution of  [various types of shell scripts](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/).

JMeter in its turn can be executed in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)

so all you need to do is something like:

```
test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - echo 'Running JMeter Test'
        - /path/to/your/jmeter/bin/jmeter -n -t yourtest.jmx -l result.jtl
```

Make sure that [JMeter is installed](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans/) on the Gitlab runner machine.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T. I'm going to try this out. I need to install Jmeter on the gitlab runner machine. I will update the status after trying.

Comment: @Dmitri did you manage to get jmeter installed on gitlab runner, how did you do that? Did you push an image that gitlab could pull and use

Comment: @deb Were you able to set up Jmeter on gitlab runner ? if yes, how did you do it ?